# ansible npm install never completes

Tags: node.js, npm, ansible

I'm using Ansible to automagically install and update my node application. When I get to my 'npm install' task, it hangs. I've let it run for about 45 minutes and it just never completes, nor throws an error.

When I run 'npm i' manually on the host, it throws a warning about a deprecated package. Does anyone know how to work that into the ansible play?

```
  - name: npm module install
    command: npm install chdir={{ home_dir.stdout }}/{{ item.code_dir }}
    with_items:
       processes
```

Quick update:

I also tried it using the npm module to the same effect. I do not get prompted for the deprecated package name.

```
  - name: npm install
    npm: path="{{ home_dir.stdout }}/{{ item.code_dir }}"
    with_items:
      processes
```

Comment: "with_items" takes an array, not a hash. In other word, "`processes`" should be "`- processes`".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which affected it more, but I fixed this by doing 2 things:

1. The deprecated package happened to be something I needed to globally install anyway, so I assigned it to another task which handles global var install and updated the package name.
2. This host hadn't ssh'd to the repo host before, so I ssh'd to it and added it to known_hosts.

After these, my play works as expected. (thumbsup)

(Edit) Upon review, it looks like the known_hosts was the problem all along. When I looked back at the logs with the deprecation warning, I saw the known_hosts prompt before it. Hope this helps someone.